# conditional operator without assigning to variable

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, operators

I'm fiddling with conditional operators on html canvas and would like a simple and efficient method to change a strokecolor with a conditional operator. I can't seem to find a good example online that does it in one line.

The following is how I would do it without a conditional operator:

```
if (shape.strokecolor == 'black'){
    shape.strokecolor = 'red';
}
else if (shape.strokecolor == 'red'){
    shape.strokecolor = 'black';
}
```

I thought I could improve this by using a conditional operator. I found this to be working:

```
var strokecol = shape.strokecolor == 'black' ? 
                shape.strokecolor = 'red' : 
                shape.strokecolor == 'red' ? 
                shape.strokecolor = 'black' : 
                shape.strokecolor = 'red';
```

So this would be:

- evaluate if strokecolor is black
- if true, change it to red,
- if false, evaluate if strokecolor is red
- if true, change it to black,
- if false, leave it red.

It seems the last line is required by the operator structure, but is redundant to me. It also seems I have to assign the result to a variable, which I do not require as the changes take effect anyway. And I thought the use of a conditional operator would reduce my code, but this way doesn't really help.

I don't think I'm doing it properly...
My main question is if I can use conditional operators like this without assigning to a variable and secondly, if anybody knows how to improve the given code as efficiently as possible (with or without the use of a conditional operator)? Thank you.

Comment: To improve the code I would keep the first version.

Comment: Arghh! Just use `if/else` — it is clear and easy to understand. Ternary operators are good for simple assignments of the form `something = condition ? value : other_value`. If you nest them they become horrible. If you make the condition or value expressions have side effects then they become horrible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the conditional operator to produce a value, not side-effects (like assignments). You can then assign that value to the appropriate place. If the only possible colors were black and red, you’d write it like this:

```
shape.strokecolor = shape.strokecolor == 'black' ? 'red' : 'black';
```

To maintain the original behavior on other colors, you’d need to assign the property back to itself:

```
shape.strokecolor = shape.strokecolor == 'black' ? 'red' :
                    shape.strokecolor == 'red' ? 'black' :
                    shape.strokecolor;
```

but that’s not really better than the original `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you nest a ternary, a puppy dies.

```
shape.strokecolor = shape.strokecolor.startsWith('b') ? 'red' : 'black';
```